# Problem with struts2 redirectAction result when using BigIP

Tags: redirect, struts2, websphere, big-ip

I am using struts2 (2.1.6) and want to redirect to *Action2* from *Action1*.

**struts.xml:**

```
<action name="Action1" class="Action1">
    <result name="success" type="redirectAction">Action2</result>
</action>

<action name="Action2" class="Action2">
    <result name="success">/demo.jsp</result>
</action>
```

This works as expected: `http://myserver:9064/demo/Action1` redirects to `http://myserver:9064/demo/Action2` (tested on tomcat and websphere).

But when I put my app behind BigIP, `redirectAction` no longer behaves as expected.

`http://mybigip/demo/Action1` is expected to redirect to `http://mybigip/demo/Action2`, instead it redirects to `http://mybigip:9064/demo/Action2` (note that my app's port number gets appended) which gives a 404 error. I got same result for `type="redirect"` also.

Any pointer to solve this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. In fact this is not happening just for Struts. It happens in general with any `Response.sendRedirect` or `RequestDispatcher.forward`. Also, this behavior is noticed when the app is deployed in WebSphere and not when in Tomcat.

The links below has more details:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/rweb_custom_props.html
(look for the custom property `httpsIndicatorHeader`)

Also:

```
http://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/solutions/public/1000/800/sol1871.html
```